# Color a certain portion of horizontal manager

Tags: blackberry

I have a Horizontal manager having 3 label fields shown has "1:00  Event1"  in the screen ,i want to set background color for hfm only covering 1:00 ,how can i do this ?

```
HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager_left15 = new HorizontalFieldManager(
                Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

        horizontalFieldManager_left15.add(time15Label);
        horizontalFieldManager_left15.add(min15Label);

         horizontalFieldManager_left15.add(evetnLabel);
```

Thanks

Comment: why not to set background for label only?

Answer (score 1):

refer this -

```
HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager_left15 = new HorizontalFieldManager(
            Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

LabelField lb = new LabelField(time15Label)  {
```

//Setting backgroundColor of the Text

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
         graphics.setColor(Color.LAVENDAR);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
```

//Setting backgroundColor of the TextArea

```
 protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {
         graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.GOLDENROD);
         graphics.clear();
        }
    };



   horizontalFieldManager_left15.add(time15Label);
```